# How to manipulate the URL from example.com/search/?s=some to example.com/search/some

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a search form on my website. When submitting the form, it is processed by my index.php, so the URL would be like index.php?s=some. Now I added a few rewrite rules in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?s=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ index.php?s=$2&f=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ index.php?s=$2&f=$1&t=$3 [QSA,L]
```

My form has the action "search", it looks like this:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="search">
```

Now what happens when submitting is that you get redirected to example.com/search/?s=some
But what I want is to be redirected to example.com/search/some
What could I add to my rewrite rules to achieve this?

Comment: i think some misunderstood here. URL re_write function is transform from example.com/search/some to example.com/index.php?s=some. But in your case, apache didnt handle it, it browser responsible to translate  from form to url (GET). so if you want clearer URL, you must redirect it first.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem, how can I submit a form to be like example.com/search/some
Because when entering this url it works perfectly fine, so the problem is probably not the rewrite rules. The problem is that my form redirects to this url: example.com/search/?s=some

Comment: i think easiest way to approve that condition, by using javascript. :)

Comment: You mean to completely remove the form and just say on button click redirect to example.com/search/word-in-input-field?
I was just thinking about SEO there, I guess it is more SEO friendly to have a usual form and not some javascript code.

Comment: Yups, In form, form input always have name(key) for the variables.

Answer (score 0):

I came across http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/how-to-post-forms-to-clean-rewritten-urls when I was looking for a solution for a project of mine. The PHP involved can be a little overkill, but it does have a lot of utility.

**.htaccess**

```
# Clean up search URL
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)$ search.php?q=$1
```

**PHP**

```
<?
    // Collect the search phrase from the URL
    $qs = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['q']);

    // Clean up by removing unwanted characters
    $qsclean = ereg_replace("[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]", " ", $qs);

    // Remove multiple adjacent spaces
    while (strstr($qsclean, "  ")) {
       $qsclean = str_replace("  ", " ", $qsclean);
    }

    // Prefix each keyword with a + (for the SQL statement)
    $qsql = "+".str_replace(" ", " +", $qsclean);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use the post method ?
I thing this method make more complex programming
Please use the post method. it is more secure.

Comment: In my case it doesn't make sense to use POST as I want the user to be able to directly visit example.com/search/someword without having to submit a form.